# Java CompletableFuture applyToEither method operates on the first completed future or randomly chooses one from two?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

From Oracle document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#applyToEither(java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage,java.util.function.Function)

> `applyToEither`

> `<U> CompletionStage<U> applyToEither​(CompletionStage<? extends T> other, Function<? super T,U> fn)`

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when **either this or the other given stage** complete normally, is executed with the corresponding result as argument to the supplied function. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

It says it applies to "either this or the other", which I think is not clear. I wonder whether it chooses the first completed future or just randomly picks up one from the two?

Comment: I think this is left unspecified because there can be race conditions: if both `CompletableFuture`s complete at the same time it is non-deterministic (because of race conditions) which result will be used. On the other hand, if one of the `CompletableFuture`s completes way ahead of the other I would expect it to use the first available result.

Answer (score 0):

It chooses the first completed future.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> task("Peter", 100)); // Generate "Peter", sleep 100ms
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> task("John", 200)); // Generate "John", sleep 200ms

CompletableFuture<Void> future3 = future2.acceptEither(future1, (text) -> {
  Truth.assertThat(text).isEqualTo("Peter"); // Expected value is "Peter" from future1   
});

future3.get()
```

The result is the same as swapped future variables:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future3 = future1.acceptEither(future2, (text) -> {
  Truth.assertThat(text).isEqualTo("Peter"); // Expected value is "Peter" from future1   
});
```